# changing dateformat sql

Tags: sql

On loading a date column from salesforce, I receive it in this format: `2017-01-31 22:00:00`. I want convert this to the german format and load into sql table without time.

Also, which datatype should I initialize in creating column in table?

Comment: You probably should _not_ be trying to do this.  Please tell us which version of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: You may have to ask these questions 1.The time you get is of what format ? is it UTC 2. what is the database timezone

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I guess you know about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - I did not once I was new. Maybe you could also include some sample-SQL you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try using the Convert function if you're using MSSQL

```
select Convert(nvarchar(10),GETDATE(),101)
```

This will create mm/dd/yyyy
if you need more samples please look at w3schools to convert time in different formats
    https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: thanks for the idea.it works .I found the mistake .it need to be  in date format in create table statement for date column and varchar datatype for target and date datatype source both tables.then it works.